# How to set a float variable as offset in panda's rolling window?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, rolling-computation

I have a dataframe which has timestamps as indexes. In order to do the data analysis I had to "break" in pieces the dataframe. So now I have a lot of dataframes with different time periods, for example:

This is one part of the first dataframe:

[image]

This is another part with different time period:

[image]

I want to calculate the rolling().mean() in the time period of each dataframe, so in order to do that, I have to set as an offset, a variable that is equal with the time period of each dataframe.
For example:
df=df.rolling('t').mean()
Where t is 12s for the dataframe in image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrkhE.png) and 10s in image [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hMTu.png).
I tried to do it like this but I get the error: passed window is not compatible with a datetimelike index.
So how can I change that, is it another way I can do it?

Comment: Would image 2 not be 9? I want to make sure I understand your expected results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.